# Cypress and Typescript. Get element with the highest title

Tags: typescript, if-statement, max, cypress

I've got few elements with titles like this:

template 2021-4-7 9:50:53 
template 2021-4-7 10:35:52 
template 2021-4-7 10:38:17 
template 2021-4-7 9:50:24 
template 2021-4-7 11:27:10 
template 2021-4-7 11:24:21

and I would like to select the latest one, so I wrote method like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addLatestTemplateToSheet', () => {
  let templateTitle: string;
  workbookEditor.leftMenu.templateMenuButton.click();
  workbookEditor.leftMenu.templateItem
    .each(($templateItem, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        templateTitle = $templateItem.attr('title');
      }
      else{
        if (templateTitle < $templateItem.attr('title')) {
          templateTitle = $templateItem.attr('title');
        }
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      //next part of code
    });
});
```

Unfortunately it does not works, I get the first item from the list.
How should I correct my method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.spread()` followed by `.then()` to select one element from a collection, e.g.

```
cy.get('li')
  .spread((...listElements) => {
    const sortedListElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(listElements).sort(...);
    return sortedListElements[0];
  })
  .then((listElement) => {
    // do what you need with the item
  });
```